# What is wrong with template definition?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am getting numerous C++ errors on the following definition for a template class for memo-ization:

```
template < typename K, typename V > class Memo{
public:
    Memo( int n ) : map( unordered_map< K, V >( 4 * n / 3 ) ) {}
    bool contains( K key ) { return map.find( K ) != map.end(); }
    V* get( K key ) {
        unordered_map< K, V >::iterator iter;
        iter = map.find( K );
        if ( map.end() != iter )
            return &( iter->second );
        else
            return NULL;
    }
private:
    unordered_map< K, V > map;
};
```

I'm getting the following error messages compiling under Eclipse on Windows:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\XorQuadruples.o" "..\\src\\XorQuadruples.cpp" 
..\src\XorQuadruples.cpp: In member function 'bool Memo<K, V>::contains(K)':
..\src\XorQuadruples.cpp:60:59: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  bool contains( K key ) { return map.end() != map.find( K ); }
                                                           ^
..\src\XorQuadruples.cpp: In member function 'V* Memo<K, V>::get(K)':
..\src\XorQuadruples.cpp:62:3: error: need 'typename' before 'std::unordered_map<K, V>::iterator' because 'std::unordered_map<K, V>' is a dependent scope
   unordered_map< K, V >::iterator iter = map.find( K );
   ^
..\src\XorQuadruples.cpp:62:35: error: expected ';' before 'iter'
   unordered_map< K, V >::iterator iter = map.find( K );
                                   ^
..\src\XorQuadruples.cpp:63:21: error: 'iter' was not declared in this scope
   if ( map.end() != iter )
```

What is wrong with this definition?

Comment: Please share the actual error messages.

Comment: `map.find( K )` won't work.  K is a type.

Comment: There are a lot of restriction on parameter `K` of the `unordered_map`... and you shouldn't  be `using namespace std;`

Comment: `map( unordered_map< K, V >( 4 * n / 3 ) )` can simply be `map(4 * n / 3 )`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, your call to `find()` needs a value, not a type. Secondly, the `iter` variable declaration needs to be preceded with `typename`, because it's in a dependent context.

Fixing these issues looks like this:

```
 bool contains( K key ) { return map.find( key ) != map.end(); }  // use key
    V* get( K key ) {
        typename unordered_map< K, V >::iterator iter;  // say typename
        iter = map.find( key );                        // use key
// ...
```

To avoid having to spell out the `typename` keyword, you can ask the compiler to deduce the type, like this:

```
auto iter = map.find(key);
```

as @Jarod42 pointed out in the comment.

Comment: or simply `auto iter = map.find( key );` :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a full working copy of your code. I just fixed the compilation issues, without any cleaning or making the code better. (Tested on VS2015)

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template <typename K, typename V > 
class Memo 
{
public:
   Memo(int n) : map(unordered_map< K, V >(4 * n / 3)) {}
   bool contains(K key) 
   { 
      return map.find(key) != map.end(); 
   }

   V* get(K key) 
   {
      typename unordered_map< K, V >::iterator iter;
      iter = map.find(key);
      if (map.end() != iter)
         return &(iter->second);
      else
         return NULL;
   }
private:
   unordered_map< K, V > map;
};


int main()
{
   Memo<int, double> mem(10);

   bool x = mem.contains(12);
   auto y = mem.get(13);
}
```

Comment: You should explain what about the code you had to change to get it to work, and why.  Also, the code does not compile on gcc or clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b09083ab0c343da1

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the comment. I fixed the compilation issue on Linux.